# How to strip SGML tags from a text file using Python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, beautifulsoup, sgml

I came across the [Standard Generalized Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) lately. I have acquired the corpus which is in SGML format from [EMILLE/CIIL Corpus](http://metashare.elda.org/repository/browse/the-emilleciil-corpus/abdd35c8de6f11e2b1e400259011f6ea6bce74d38dbb42d881da76c64a6adb20/). This is the documentation for this corpus:

[EMILLE Corpus Documentation](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/fass/projects/corpus/emille/MANUAL.htm)

I want to extract just the text present in the file. Encoding and Markup information of corpus from documentation is:

> The text is encoded as two-byte Unicode text. For more information on Unicode.
>   The texts are marked up in SGML using level 1 CES-compliant markup. Each file also includes a full header, which specifies the provenance of the text.

I am having a hard time stripping these tags. I tried with 'regular expression' as well as 'beautiful soup' but it is not working. This is the sample text file. The language I want to preserve is Punjabi.

[image: Sample text file]

Comment: This is xml and there are multiple xml parsers out there that you can use. In python, I like `lxml` the best - its a front-end to the `libxml` libraries and is efficient. `ElementTree` is a pure-python implementation. Don't even try to use regex for this, its incredibly difficult for xml.

Comment: Another option is to use XSLT. Suppose you want the text but you also want to break paragraphs on `<p>...</p>` boundaries. That can be expressed in XSLT compactly (if somewhat cryptically).

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney. I'm gonna use lxml. I will let you know when it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Assuming this is the url where the file is
html = requests.get('http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/fass/projects/corpus/emille/MANUAL.htm').content

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

textData = bsObj.findAll('p')

for item in textData:
    print item.get_text()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. It is indeed helpful, but there are some things missing from the output. I don't know why. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Or
you can use simple regular expressions; if data is your string that contains tags start with < and end with >, everything in between those tags will be discarded you can limit more than a single whitespace to one and strip the data.

```
data = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', data)
data = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', data)
data = data.strip()
```